# how to take screen shot of android app when testcase fails on real device

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, appium

I am trying to get screenshot on android/iPhone device with following code:

```
File temp = ((TakesScreenshot (AndroidDriver) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(temp, new File("D:\\my1.png"));
```

I am getting error `unable to handle screenshot` in Appium version
1.4.8. Please help me to resolve this issue with my native android app.

Comment: Please format your code to improve readability.

Comment: also provide appium server logs.

Comment: yes sir i do provide a error log but i have a question "android applications native view can we capture? through webdriver using appium "

Comment: appium Log  is below                                                                           info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/d6d56bae-6618-4f9c-9fe8-e09e9a7444e7/screenshot {}  info: Proxying [GET /wd/hub/session/d6d56bae-6618-4f9c-9fe8-e09e9a7444e7/screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session/7a704e3ebcb6c336830a8b004010b5e0/screenshot] with body: {} info: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"7a704e3ebcb6c336830a8b004010b5e0","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {\"code\":-32603,\"message\":\"Unable to capture screenshot\"}\n

Comment: console log: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Unable to capture screenshot"}
  (Session info: webview=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with following code `File temp=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); FileUtils.copyFile(temp, new File("D:\\my1.png"));`

Comment: this is what i tried my first attempt then i tried to add android driver as if it supports takescreenshot   so....

Comment: No need to cast to android driver, this will take the screen shot and will save to the specified location.

Comment: i tried with ur code still it is throwing error as console log: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Unable to capture screenshot"} (Session info: webview= ..............

Comment: and let me clear iam taking screen shot of native android app page . using appium as interface between device and webdriver

Comment: But the above code is working fine for me and i'm also using the same code in appium for native app to take screen shot.

Comment: Great and glad to know.

Answer (score 0):

this is resolved by switching the context to native from web --- driver.context("NATIVE_APP");